# Submersible well pump overheated--determining cause?

Tags: well, well-pump

Does anyone know what would be the most likely cause of a well pump overheating? Something happened with mine, causing it to run continuously, and now it's melted to the PVC casing down there, and can't be pulled up.

There's no way to look at it to find out, and well contractors have told me overheating is not commonly age-related. My insurance company is saying it is, and won't cover it, so if anyone knows how to find out what happened, or at least what is a more likely cause, that would be very helpful.
Thank you

Comment: I don't see a question up there. "Any advice" isn't specific enough for this Q&A site. Please revise to be more clear what you're asking.

Comment: A well driller should be able to get it out of the hole (possibly in tiny bits), so you should not be looking at a "whole new well" just for a stuck dead pump. As for weaseling out of coverage, that's the insurance industry for you.

Comment: The older well pump does not have an auto-switch. The overheating can be caused by a period of low water level and the pump running dry over an extended time.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, Thank you for your comment. They definitely can get it to come up, but it will break and I will be without water for a long time. And the damage down there is severe enough they can't replace it with a new one in the same spot, so either way, I need a new well (at least according to several drillers) Maybe I can get them to pull it up once the new one is in and show it to my insurance co.

Comment: Sorry about your problem. If your pump is like mine was a few years back it has a switch where the power goes to. From that switch 3 wires go to the pump. One of the wires is common, power, and start. The relay allows both the power and start to come on for a period of time causing the pump motor to start then the start opens and only two wires have current.  It was a single phase motor. If that relay does not open both windings will be on and cause it to draw an excess amount of current. This is my first encounter with a PVC casing. If the worst thing happens have them use metal casing.

Comment: How did you discover something was wrong?  It sounds like it still works and you still have water pressure.

Comment: Are you saying your well casing is PVC? Just asking my last home build was only 11 years ago and we used steel never even knew of pvc for the casing maybe because I am in a seismic zone but if a pump could overheat and was in contact with plastic it could melt into the plastic, my question would be where are the centering doilies and antitwist or torque preventers with these the pump would be centered.